# created and modified in CakePHP 1.1

Tags: cakephp

A simple question: in both CakePHP 1.2 and 1.3, created and modified fields will be automatically populated:

> By defining a created or modified field in your database table as
>   datetime fields, CakePHP will recognize those fields and populate them
>   automatically whenever a record is created or saved to the database
>   (unless the data being saved already contains a value for these
>   fields).

A preliminary search of the Cookbook finds no such section for CakePHP 1.1.  Is this functionality in 1.1 at all, or was it introduced with 1.2?  If the former, bonus points given for ideas on how to replicate it in 1.1...

Comment: I believe this functionality was in 1.1. Try it and see? If you look (1.3) in CAKE/libs/model/model.php` around line 1240 you'll see how cake does it.

Comment: @Ross: Yeah, "just try it and see" is probably a highly reasonable suggestion!

Comment: And why are you using such an old version of cake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is available in CakePHP 1.1, see http://api11.cakephp.org/model__php5_8php-source.html#l00867